# How to construct SQL (Spatialite) to search for matches from a list of codes in a field also containing a list?

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite

I have a (.TAB / polyline) layer on QGIS. There's a field in this ('RCode') which contains unique codes (each very distinct from the others) - BUT note that it can contain more than one code or none at all. These are used for highlighting polylines where there's a code we're interested in.

I have no problems working on a single match at a time (using LIKE), but today I have a *list* of about 40 codes I'm interested in. I don't want to repeat the exercise 40 times but to match polylines which have any of the codes in the list. So in other words I have a list of matching items looking to match any items in this list with items in a field which itself contains a list of items.

I could write a long and complex SQL statement by hand, including writing in each code by hand. The potential for (non-detectable) error exists. I'd prefer something more graceful so that errors can be detected, or at least so that the exercise is relatively easy to reproduce another time.

I'm intending to do an SQL based query - setting up a virtual layer (so using the Spatialite dialect of SQL I believe) - to allow me to show matching polylines and distinguish them from non-matching polylines. Other solutions may be quite acceptable.

As I can't change the main polyline layer, its design, or its file format this may limit solutions a little. Obviously I can copy the data, but I'd like to use the original file so that future changes are included automatically. The codes to be matched are currently in a spreadsheet, but this is a flexible arrangement.

Comment: Even though you are doing this within QGIS, this is really just an SQL question, which would be better suited on [so]. In fact [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423979/multiple-like-in-sqlite) may give you an idea, although it requires an extra extension.

Comment: Can the extensions mentioned on the Stack Overflow site be utilised from within QGIS capabilities? Maybe this turns my question into one appropriate for gis.stackexchange.com? The data isn't in a spatialite database - I'm asking about the core capabilities of QGIS. And is there really no better way than using (assuming the extension is applicable) - to quote from the Stack Overflow answer - "x.value MATCH 'foo OR bar' OR ..... [repeat 40 values]" ? (But thanks for the pointers)

Comment: Is it as simple as this? RCode values listed in a simple table (e.g. csv file - obviously no geometries). Crucially, codes need to be listed here using the wildcards that LIKE expects  - so if I have a RCode=AA it has to be listed in the simple table as %AA%. Then use SELECT * FROM "MyPolylines" JOIN "RCodesTable" ON MyPolylines.RCodes LIKE RCodesTable.RCode

Answer (score 1):

Not a spatial question, so likely to get closed...

However, I think what you want to use an IN statement:

```
select * from myTable where RCode in ('code1', 'code2', 'code3', etc.)
```

Comment: Hmmm... fair point about it not being spatial. Hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: I've been working on the assumption that your proposed solution won't work - and I'm still inclined to believe so - surely your suggestion @DPSSpatial only works if RCode has single values in it (rather than the list I specify).

Comment: @Rostranimin well I've read the question a few times and can't figure out what you're doing that my solution won't solve ... my apologies if i'm not properly understanding.

Comment: Hi DPSSpatial - equally possible I'm missing something or being unclear, but this solution only recognises matches when the RCode field exactly matches the code listed in the brackets. It fails to recognise a match where the code listed in the brackets is only one of several listed (separated by spaces) in the RCode field in the data. In the first question paragraph I'm trying to make clear that for just one row in the data the RCode field may contain several codes. This may be an odd convention but I'm working with an established system that I can't challenge (and actually it works OK).